# WinForm method does not have access to panel properties

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make a `WinForm` app with a expandable menu. I'm trying to create a method that will change a panel propierties in `form1` but it sees the value as false even if it is not? I got message box with "recognition as false". Instead of code I would rather a nice explanation

```
private void JobSelectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //button to open a panel with "menu"
    if (jobPanel.Visible == false)
    {
        // the panel is visible from this point
        jobPanel.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        jobPanel.Visible = false;
    }            
}

public void fla(bool flag)
{   //method inside form1 and it should make jobPanel.Visible = false             
    if (jobPanel.Visible == false)
        MessageBox.Show("recognition as false");
    else jobPanel.Visible = false;
}

private void notification_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{   // user control that will call the method
    caseNBvalue = lbl_caseNB.Text;
    profile f2 = new profile();

    f2.fla(true);
}
```

Comment: You need a reference to form1 if this code isn't in form1.  `profile f2 = new profile();` tells me you might be referencing the wrong form, since that form isn't being shown.  The "new" keyword should be sounding alarm bells in your head.  I would also not rely on the Visible property.  It can give you false positives the way WinForms uses it.  Create your own variable that determines it is showing or not.

Comment: You are not using the `flag` parameter in the `fla()` function. I suspect that there is something missing there. Tip: you can enhance your code by replacing all that code in the `JobSelectButton_Click` function with a simple one line `jobPanel.Visible = !jobPanel.Visible;`.